# Ruby: How to either set a variable to 0 or, if it is already set, increment by 1

Tags: ruby, arrays

I know of the ||= operator, but don't think it'll help me here...trying to create an array that counts the number of "types" among an array of objects.

```
array.each do |c|
  newarray[c.type] = newarray[c.type] ? newarray[c.type]+1 ? 0
end
```

Is there a more graceful way to do this?

Comment: The second question mark should be a colon.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
types = Hash.new(-1) # It feels like this should be 0, but to be
                     # equivalent to your example it needs to be -1
array.each do |c|
  types[c.type] += 1
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Array#fetch` method for which you can provide a default value if the index doesn't exist:

```
array.each do |c|
  newarray[c.type] = newarray.fetch(c.type, -1) + 1
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
array.each do |c|
  newarray[c.type] = 1 + (newarray[c.type] || -1)
end
```

Alternatively

```
array.each do |c|
  newarray[c.type] ||= -1
  newarray[c.type] += 1
end
```

Comment: I like your second one.  The only drawback is that it's the sort of thing that someone coming along later may take for being a mistake.  If using it in production, I'd add a quick comment explaining why I'm doing it that way.

Comment: I like the second way. It's two lines and potentially two assignments, but more readable than complex conditionals or whatever shoved on one line.

Answer (score 3):

`||=` does help:

```
types = {}
array.each do |c|
    types[c.class] ||= 0
    types[c.class] += 1
end
```

Comment: That'll set it to 1 the first time through...
    newarray[c.type] ||= -1
    newarray[c.type] += 1

Comment: Yes, isn't that what we want? For example, if array is [1] then types will become {Fixnum=>1}. And we have 1 Fixnum.

Comment: We want it to be set to 0 at the end of the loop, not 1, if !types[c.class].

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `newarray` is named oddly, since in Ruby and most other languages, arrays are indexed by integers, not random Objects like `Class`. It's more likely this is a `Hash`.

Also, you should be using `c.class`, instead of `c.type`, which is deprecated.

Finally, since you're creating a `Hash`, you can use `inject` like so:

```
newarray = array.inject( {} ) do |h,c|
  h[c.class] = h.key?(c.class) ? h[c.class]+1 : 0
  h
end
```

Or, for a one-liner:

```
newarray = array.inject( {} ) { |h,c| h[c.class] = h.key?(c.class) ? h[c.class]+1 : 0 ; h }
```

As you can see, this gives the desired results:

```
irb(main):001:0> array = [1, {}, 42, [], Object.new(), [1, 2, 3]]
=> [1, {}, 42, [], #<Object:0x287030>, [1, 2, 3]]
irb(main):002:0> newarray = array.inject( {} ) { |h,c| h[c.class] = h.key?(c.class) ? h[c.class]+1 : 0 ; h }
=> {Object=>0, Hash=>0, Array=>1, Fixnum=>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby 1.8.7 or later you can use `group_by` and then turn each list of elements into count - 1, and make a hash from the array returned by `map`.

```
Hash[array.group_by(&:class).map { |k,v| [k, v.size-1] }]
```