# Ruby: How to increment a number that may be nil?

Tags: ruby

How could I simplify this in Ruby:

```
x = (x || 0) + 1
```

?

Comment: looks pretty good to me (well, x2 = (x || 0) + 1 would be better), more explicit that "magic" to_i conversions.

Comment: How much simpler can you get? Why would you think there is room to improve on your existing solution?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `to_i` to convert `nil` to `0`

`x = x.to_i + 1`

Or you can use `succ`

`x = x.to_i.succ`

Answer (score 7):

That depends on what you consider simple. You could use

```
(x ||= 0) += 1
```

but I think I'd settle for your version.

If `x` is a Hash value, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369388/ruby-how-to-either-set-a-variable-to-0-or-if-it-is-already-set-increment-by-1) for using default values in Hashes.

Comment: That does not seem to work. The part in parentheses `(x ||= 0)` returns an integer, not x. You cannot alter an integer with the `+=` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Your code may end in an error:

```
x = 'a'
x = (x || 0) + 1 #can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError)
```

There is the possibility to use `to_i` with `+1` or `succ` (see [Chandras answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440954/how-to-increment-an-unknown-value-in-ruby/7440969#7440969))

But perhaps only `succ` will help you also:

```
x = x.succ if x.respond_to?(:succ)
```

The correct answer depend on your input data and what you need.